# What percentage of users actively answer questions?

Tags: discussion, statistics

How can I determine the percentage of users who actively answer questions in any given Stack Exchange forum?

By active, I mean have answered at least one question within the last 12 months, regardless of whether their answer was selected or upvoted.

I'm as much interested in how I can find the answer myself as I am in the actual answer.

Comment: You can find the answer using SEDE, the Stack Exchange Data Explorer.

Comment: Check out [the SEDE tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using SEDE, the following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1357532/users-with-1-answers-in-last-12-months) gives the desired results:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) As AnsweringUsers
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS AnswerCount
  FROM Users
  LEFT JOIN Posts
  ON Users.Id = Posts.OwnerUserId
  WHERE Posts.PostTypeId = 2
  AND Posts.CreationDate >= DATEADD(month, -12, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  GROUP BY Users.Id
  HAVING Count(*) > 0
) AS X;
```

A query for total users shows 13,764,888. However, as @VLAZ suggested, many of those users are stale and have not logged on in years. It makes more sense to consider only active users. For simplicity, I used `Users.LastAccessDate`, which includes any login within the query window. Here's the [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1357843/active-users-within-last-12-months) for active users in the last 12 months:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) As ActiveUsers
FROM Users
WHERE Users.LastAccessDate >= DATEADD(month, -12, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Here are the results for Stack Overflow on Jan 13, 2020.

#### Users Who Answered

| Query Window | Users Answered | Active Users | % of Active Users | % of Total Users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Last 12 months | 529,224 | 5,019,518 | 10.5% | 3.8% |
| Last 6 months | 297,102 | 3,558,794 | 8.3% | 2.2% |
| Last 3 months | 163,368 | 2,729,044 | 6.0% | 1.2% |
| Last 1 month | 59,831 | 1,925,073 | 3.1% | 0.4% |

#### Users Who Posted

| Query Window | Users Posted | Active Users | % of Active Users | % of Total Users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Last 12 months | 1,210,741 | 5,019,518 | 24.1% | 8.8% |
| Last 6 months | 691,999 | 3,558,794 | 19.4% | 5.0% |
| Last 3 months | 391715 | 2729044 | 14.4% | 2.8% |
| Last 1 month | 153,814 | 1,925,073 | 8.0% | 1.1% |

Comment: It might be useful to only check "active" accounts. Although, I'm not exactly sure how that would be formulated. I don't think SEDE gives thorough information for user activity but you can at least consider users who have commented, posted, and cast votes. You can choose the timeframe for that. The idea is that many accounts are abandoned for one reason or another, so counting them as "not answering" might not be very useful, since they aren't doing anything and likely haven't logged in for many years.

Comment: Good suggestion @VLAZ. I'll update my query to look for users with LastAccessDate within the last 12 months.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to [these sort of questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=Active+answer) can be found using the Stack Exchange Data Explorer.

Here is one [example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1197888/active-answerers-3-questions-per-week#graph):

[image: Users answering more than 3 questions per week this past year on Stack Overflow]

Changing that to one per week gives 70-85 thousand users, with the peak during May 2020, or approximately 0.55% of the users (out of 14 million) are that active.

Comment: Did you see a dip?

Comment: From 13 to 12 in the past year, on 3 answers per week, isn't really a very noticeable dip; which could easily be counteracted by many new users engaging actively and only answering 2 questions per week.